# Spring Data JPA Query + Crosstable

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I do have three database tables (MariaDB):

```
A:
+----+
| ID |[...]
+----+

B:
+----+
| ID |[...]
+----+

A_B (Crosstable)
+-----+-----+
| AID | BID |
+-----+-----+
```

Now I have an instance of entity A and would like to get a list using Spring Data JPA repositories:

```
public interface BRepository extends JPARepository<B, Long> {
    List<B> bList = findByAId(Integer aId);
}
```

This solution does *not* work. What is the correct way to resolve that relation? The documentation only shows the very simple queries, i.e. querying by column value.

The entities themselves do work, I can store data correctly. Let me know, if I did not provide all necessary information.

Added information (relevant parts of entities):

```
Entity B:
[...]
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "B")
List<A> aList;
[...]

Entity A:
[...]
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "A_B",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(
                        name = "a_id",
                        referencedColumnName = "id"
                )
        },
        inverseJoinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(
                        name = "b_id",
                        referencedColumnName = "id"
                )
)
private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, at the end it was much easier than I thought. I just had to call:

```
List<b> bList = aRepository.findOne(id).getBList();
```